# Java application stuck when using synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I have a class that starts a few threads. Each thread (extends Thread) calls a new instance of class WH, class WH has a variable that is to be shared among all threads. So the hierarchy looks like:

```
class S extends Thread {
....
....
  WH n = new WH(args);
....
....
}
```

Now class WH has a variable that is to be shared, declared as:

```
private static volatile Integer size;

One of the functions tries to access size through Synchronized:
Synchronized (size) { // Program gets stuck at this line
 ... stuff ...
}
```

It gets stuck even if I spawn off just one thread. Any idea why this is happening? (FYI- I do not want to use AtomicInteger based on my design choices)

Thanks

Comment: well **your** design choices aren't working right now, and `AtomicInteger` is designed just for this exact use case. Shared state is hard to do correctly, best use the tools others have designed and tested and proven. Good Luck.

Comment: I cannot use AtomicInteger since I need to get the value of size, check a condition on it, and increment or not based on the condition. So I have to do a get then possibly an increment on it. I still need locking in that case. Also, if I use a ConcurrentHashMap it gets stuck too.

Comment: Try to use another lock in `Synchronized` keyword, for example, `WH.class` (if it is not used somewhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that locking on a **Non-Final** variable reference **has useless semantics**.

Anytime you see something doing a `synchronized(var);` and `var` is an instance or static variable and isn't marked `final`, it is an error, because anything can come along and do a `var = new Thing();` and now there are at least 2 threads that can operate on that block at the same time, this is a logical error no exceptions. Every Java lint style checker flags this as a critical error, just because the compiler doesn't catch this doesn't mean it has any usefulness in any case.

In this case, you are exposing these useless semantics by changing the value of the immutable `Integer` class.

Your `Integer` variable `size` is non-Final and is `Immutable` which means every time you change it you **must change the reference** to the new object that represents the new value and every thread will get a **new** and **different** reference to lock onto. Thus **no locking**.

Use a `private static final AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger();`

And then you can `synchronize(size);` since `size` is now `final` you can mutate it in place and get the intended and correct semantics.

or you can `synchronize(some_other_final_reference);` and use a regular `int` as long as that reference that is synchronized on is `final` and can be in scope of any thread that needs to acquire a handle to it, it will work.

Personally I would use the `AtomicInteger` it is more cohesive that way, you are locking on what you don't want changing by any other thread, self-documenting and clear intentions.

Comment: That would seem to answer the question, "why doesn't my `synchronized` keyword block other threads?" which is opposite of this question. I'm not sure why this code, broken though it is, would cause a single thread to block -- unless some other thread were also locking on an `Integer` which happened to be the same instance due to `valueOf` caching.

Comment: @yshavit without seeing all the other code it is only speculation, but I would guess that some kind of race condition is happening because of something inside the synchronized block or because of a side effect of the `volatile` keyword and it is just reporting that line as the last place of execution. To paraphrase my Aikido Sensei *"Doing concurrency is easy, doing concurrency correctly is **hard**"*

Comment: *doing a **synchronized(var); and var isn't marked final**, it is an error* ==> **No, it's it**. Java wouldn't allow you to compile it, or else would throw a `RuntimeException` or an `Error` if it was indeed an error.  What I'd agree with is that it is difficult both to find a use case that would justify it and to do it right. I just think it is very bad to try to discourage bad and potentially-harmful habits (such as synchronizing on non-final fields) by lying. Just tell that it is evil, that's enough, and does not create disinformation.

Comment: @Bruno it is a logic error full stop, there is not a single semantic reason to potentially and non-deterministically give every different thread a different lock to a resource that is supposed to be protected. You can argue all you want but plain and simple it is a logic error in every case. Every lint program for Java flags it as a critical error in every case.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, you are too narrow-minded: you assume that the point of synchronizing on anything else than a final field is to cause trouble. If you can't see how it can be useful, would you at least agree with me that the guys developing **Apache Tomcat** seem know what they are doing? Take a look at how Tomcat's 7.0.25 SingleSignOn is implemented (`synchronized(lookup(ssoId)) {...}`). Ok, maybe they don't know what they are doing. Let's then assume that the guys developing **Google Guava**: take a look at Guava's 11.0.1 LocalCache.java ().

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, we could continue to find notable examples of this, but you already have lots of material to study. About "lint" programs: they can't possibly know if something is right or wrong; they can only suggest to the developer that something might be wrong, based on collective knowledge of the people behind the "lint" programs, on what they've seen (for instance, maybe 99% of time people synchronize on non-final fields disastrous things happen). But then again, maybe they are all wrong, and you should file bugs against Tomcat and Guava for this "logic error full stop", or fix them.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use AtomicInteger since I need to get the value of size,
>   check a condition on it, and increment or not based on the condition.
>   So I have to do a get then possibly an increment on it. I still need
>   locking in that case.

I believe what you are describing is something that AtomicInteger can definitely do, without locking, via the `compareAndSet()` method, no?  Though the only supported test is equality, so maybe that won't work for you.

Also, if you are planning on synchronizing on the variable, then there is no need to also make it `volatile`.